# Online SQL database for a Flutter mobile application?

Tags: sql, flutter, cloud

**Backgroud**: Currently we use Google Sheets to store data. We service clients and append their info into a single sheet (Its just a sinple row of data with name, phone number, email, payment method etc). We have a team of 5 people who do the work and input it in google sheets and we get max 10 customers daily.

**Task**: I want to make a Flutter Android application that my team can use to input the data into textfields and tap submit to append the info in this SQL database. The app should also be able to query data from the database. Rarely we will have to update the info as well.

**Problem**: I have made applications before with SwiftUI, CoreData, Flutter, local MySQL and JavaFX. My problem is that I'm not experienced with hosting databases and I'm not sure what services/techologies to use to connect this database with flutter. (I keep on hearing the terms php, apache, AWS RDS ...). I dont know where and how to host this database. How to integrate it with my application. Money isnt a constrant and I'll be happy to learn whatever I need to. I just would like to know what I need to do and where to start.

Comment: Checkout firebase firestore or aws amplify datastore. They are fully management cloud nosql database, with a generous free tier.

Comment: @RubensMelo Firestore is nice but I would like to use SQL here.

Comment: try https://planetscale.com/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this platform called PlanetScale, this is has really good use case and has support not only for SQL, rather it has support for a wide range of SQL and NoSQL frameworks. Also hosting is quite simple all you got to do is host on vercel and it would do the work itself. I've tried it personally and it was the easiest and hassle-free backend that I've used till date.